# How to test node.js websocket server with mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, websocket, socket.io, mocha.js

I need to test a poker game server, which based on websocket.

So, if `player1` send a message to server, server usually should send a message to other players.

I write an test block like below:

```
describe('protocol', () => {
  before(() => {
    player1 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
    player1 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
    player2 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
    player3 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
  });

  it('player1 send message1 player3 should receive' (done) => {

    //block1
    let message1 = {
      id: 'message1',
      data: 'message1'
    };

    player1.send(JSON.stringify(message1));
    player3.once('message', (message) => {

      //block2
      expect(message).equal(JSON.stringify(message1)),
      done();
    });
  });

  it('player2 send message2 player3 should also receive' (done) => {

    //block3
    let message2 = {
      id: 'message2',
      data: 'message2'
    };

    player2.send(JSON.stringify(message1));
    player3.once('message', (message) => {

      //block4
      expect(message).equal(JSON.stringify(message2)),
      done();
    });
  });
}
```

The order of execution I want was :
`block1` -> `block2` -> `block3` -> `block4`

but truly:`blocks1` -> `block3` -> `block2` -> `block4`

so the `message` of `block4` was `message1` instead of `message2`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: SORRY!!!! The order of execution of this code block was `block1` -> `block2` -> `block3` -> `block4`

Answer (score 0):

Simply answer is just move all your `playerX.send(messageX);` AFTER `playerX.once()` , that's it.

Just in mind, these call are ASYNC, so order is not important, but you need get ready for receive BEFORE you fire something.

```
describe('protocol', () => {
  before(() => {
    player1 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
    player1 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
    player2 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
    player3 = new WebSocket('ws://xxxxxx');
  });

  it('player1 send message1 player3 should receive', (done) => {

    //block1
    let message1 = {
      id: 'message1',
      data: 'message1'
    };

    player3.once('message', (message) => {

      //block2
      expect(message).equal(JSON.stringify(message1));
      done();
    });
    player1.send(JSON.stringify(message1));
  });

  it('player2 send message2 player3 should also receive', (done) => {

    //block3
    let message2 = {
      id: 'message2',
      data: 'message2'
    };

    player3.once('message', (message) => {

      //block4
      expect(message).equal(JSON.stringify(message2));
      done();
    });
  });
  player2.send(JSON.stringify(message1));
}
```

Comment: But it not effective, `BEFORE` or `AFTER` is not influential. Because `playerX.send(messageX)` and `playerX.once('xxx', listener)` was called synchronously, listener always called after those.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. My code is correct,  the problem come from other place.

Answer (score 0):

I think unit tests should pass regardless of their execution order. As far as I know, controlling execution order of tests in Mocha is not feasible.

Instead of doing that, what about setting up server per unit test to listen on different port? Then, tests should not interfere with each other.

You can do that [beforeEach and afterEach](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) hooks. Just set up a server with a randomly assigned port in beforeEach and shutdown the server in afterEach.

Answer (score 0):

on my side I use the npm module mocha-steps, which allow sequential testing. it solves a lot of testing issues on our project.